# Unable to unlock account before deploying contract to rinkeby

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-deployment, gas, myetherwallet

Each time i try to unlock my account w/ password i get the error:

`Fatal: Failed to unlock account 0x1288AB0bf7FE0Ad09d7f28bd4Ab2C06332c625a2 (no key for given address or file)`

my geth command is: `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --unlock="0x1288AB0bf7FE0Ad09d7f28bd4Ab2C06332c625a2"`

When testing this same information on myetherwallet.com and the rinkeby testnet w/ my created password I am able to access my account without a problem.

truffle.js

```
 module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      gas: 6000000,
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '4000'
    },
    rinkeby: {
      host: "localhost", // Connect to geth on the specified
      port: 8545,
      from: "0x1288AB0bf7FE0Ad09d7f28bd4Ab2B06332e625a2",
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4612388
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any step i'm missing here for deploying my contract to the testnet?

Comment: I still can't figure out the issue locally.. However I was able to deploy by generating bytecode in remix and deploying it via metamask.  Leaving issue open incase anyone can still help me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Did you use the `--pasword` command line option?

Comment: Sign the transaction and don’t unlock account, see truffle hd wallet provider

Answer (score 0):

I think your rinkeby fields are incorrect. I would consider using infura and truffle as described here to access ropsten/rinkeby and so on. Here the link
https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider